# Editing existing XML file and sending post via Jboss

Tags: python, jboss, lxml, soapui

I have the following python method which runs though an xml file and parses it, and *TRIES* to edit a field:

```
    import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random

def runThrougheTree():
    #open xml file
    with open("testxml.xml") as xml:
        from lxml import etree
        #parse
        parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=True, recover=True)
        tree = etree.parse("testxml.xml", parser)
        root= tree.getroot()
        #ATTEMPT to edit field - will not work as of now
        for ci in root.iter("CurrentlyInjured"):
            ci.text = randomCurrentlyInjured(['sffdgdg', 'sdfsdfdsfsfsfsd','sfdsdfsdfds'])
        #Overwrite initial xml file with new fields  - will not work as of now
        etree.ElementTree(root).write("testxml.xml",pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)

        #send post (Jboss)
        requests.post('http://localhost:9000/something/RuleServiceImpl', data="testxml.xml)



def randomCurrentlyInjured(ran):
    random.shuffle(ran)
    return ran[0]







#-----------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    runThrougheTree()
```

Edited XML file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rule="http://somewebsite.com/" xmlns:ws="http://somewebsite.com/" xmlns:bus="http://somewebsite.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:Respond>
         <ws:busMessage>
            <bus:SomeRef>insertnumericvaluehere</bus:SomeRef>
            <bus:Content><![CDATA[<SomeDef>
  <SomeType>ABCD</Sometype>
  <A_Message>
      <body>
        <AnonymousField>
          <RefIndicator>1111111111111</RefIndicator>
          <OneMoreType>HIJK</OneMoreType>
          <CurrentlyInjured>ABCDE</CurentlyInjured>
        </AnonymousField>
      </body>
  </A_Message>
</SomeDef>]]></bus:Content>
            <bus:MessageTypeId>somenumericvalue</bus:MessageTypeId>
         </ws:busMessage>
      </ws:Respond>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Issues:**

1. The field is not being edited.
2. Jboss error: Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
   Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Note: I have ensured that there is no characters prior to first xml tag.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You seem to think that lxml is somehow more difficult than ElementTree.

Comment: Which properties and/or methods of `xml.etree.ElementTree` are you using exactly that you think are too difficult to use in `lxml.etree.ElementTreee`?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen Thanks for the response. I've updated my post with a snippet of the xml.etree.ElementTree way of iterating through the xml file and editing. Would you be able to help me understand how I could use the lxml object to iterate through and edit fields similarly? I apologize ahead of time if this is straight forward and I am simply missing the way to do so.

Comment: Doesn't the `iter` iteration approach work as well in lxml (https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration)? Or where do you run into problems?

Comment: Will be reviewing this tomorrow morning @MartinHonnen thank you.

Comment: Hi @mzjn, I am new to stackoverflow and am trying to be as detailed as possible. I will update the title to be more appropriate/less confusing. Working on this now.

Comment: hi @mzjn, is my post more appropriate now? i can successfully post an overrwritten xml (parsed by lxml) but I don't see the fields being edited at all. Any clue as to where I may be failing? Thanks!

Comment: @MartinHonnen any thoughts?

Comment: I also believe that there is something incorrect about how I am sending my post to jboss. once I overwrite the xml file, i get "content is not allowed in prolog" even though the xml is properly formatted with no whitespaces before xml declaration. I sincerely appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot reproduce the problem (whatever it is). You have not provided a [mcve]. For example, what does "testxml.xml" look like?

Comment: Hi @mzjn, Sincerely appreciate your help. I've added an edited version of the xml file and have tried to clarify the queston much as possible. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You are trying to update the `CurrentlyInjured` element. It will not work because the element is in a CDATA section. Everything inside a CDATA section is treated as plain text, not as XML markup. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML. Using `strip_cdata=True` does not help.

Comment: Hi @mzjn, thanks for the info. Is there a way to edit this cdata that you're aware of? For example, the first thought that comes to mind is converting everything to plain text somehow, and then sending that through to Jboss.

Comment: @mzjn Quick update: So I've tried manually just taking out the CData within the xml file and then sending the post. Still getting the "content is not allowed in prolog" error. Do you have any experience with this? Also, if you add an answer with the content that you posted in your most recent comment, I'll happily accept as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was unable to use lxml, elementtree to edit the fields/post to Jboss as:

1. I had CDATA in the xml as mzjn pointed out in the comments
2. Jboss did not like the request after it had been parsed, even when the CDATA tags were removed.

Workaround/Eventual SOlution: I was able to (somewhat tediously) use .replace() in my script to edit the plaintext successfully, and then send the POST via Jboss. I hope this helps someone else someday!